# Why doesn't my Mapbox GL JS map display properly on first visit via Turbolinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapbox-gl-js, turbolinks, tailwind-css, stimulusjs

I'm trying to add Turbolinks to my Rails 6 app (I'm late to the party) and I'm having display issues with TailwindCSS & Mapbox GL JS.

If I start my journey on the page with the map (new tab or refresh the page), then everything works as expected for the duration of my visits (I can leave and return to the page with the map repeatedly & each time everything works as expected). I can even visit pages with *other* instances of Mapbox on it & those display properly (I'm slowly transitioning from isolated `script` tags on each page into StimulusJS in a way that leaves me with sevaral Mapbox-providing controllers e.g. mapcity_controller & mapstreet_controller - I don't think this is part of the problem, but I don't want to leave anything to chance).

However, if I start my journey on a different page that does not have a map (new tab or refresh the page), then navigate to a page with Mapbox on it, the `fixed` and `w-*` styles don't work. If I scroll the page, the map flows up with the content & the map doesn't fill up the entire `w-2/3` space that it should.

```html
<div data-controller="mapbox" class="flex flex-col-reverse flex-wrap mt-10 md:flex-row">
  <div class="h-full p-2 mt-64 overflow-scroll md:mt-0 lg:mt-0 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3">
    CONTENT
  </div>

  <div class="md:w-1/2 lg:w-2/3">
    <div id="map" class="fixed w-full h-64 md:w-1/2 lg:w-2/3 md:bottom-0 md:right-0 md:h-full"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought it might have been the parent `md:w-1/2 lg:w-2/3` container div, but removing that does not change behavior at all:

```html
<div data-controller="mapbox" class="flex flex-col-reverse flex-wrap mt-10 md:flex-row">
  <div class="h-full p-2 mt-64 overflow-scroll md:mt-0 lg:mt-0 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3">
    CONTENT
  </div>

  <div id="map" class="fixed w-full h-64 md:w-1/2 lg:w-2/3 md:bottom-0 md:right-0 md:h-full"></div>
</div>
```

If I remove Mapbox from the equation, everything works as expected in either visiting scenario (I always have a full width, non-scrolling right pane regardless of whether or not the page is my first visit):

```html
<div class="flex flex-col-reverse flex-wrap mt-10 md:flex-row">
  <div class="h-full p-2 mt-64 overflow-scroll md:mt-0 lg:mt-0 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3">
    LOTS OF MULTI-LINE CONTENT TO CAUSE SCROLLING
  </div>

  <div class="fixed w-full h-64 bg-blue-300 md:w-1/2 lg:w-2/3 md:bottom-0 md:right-0 md:h-full">OTHER CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing that something about my StimulusJS controller isn't working with Turbolinks properly. I've removed all of my extra code (setting zoom levels, adding sources & layers, etc), and the issue persists. I've tried using `connect` as well as `initialize`, with the same results.

```js
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'

export default class extends Controller {
  connect () {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = "my-access-token"
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11',
      center: [0,0],
      zoom: 2,
      minZoom: 1
    })
  }

  disconnect () {
    this.map.remove()
    this.map = undefined
  }
}
```

Just in case, here is my `index.js` file:

```js
import { Application } from 'stimulus'
import { definitionsFromContext } from 'stimulus/webpack-helpers'

const application = Application.start()
const context = require.context('controllers', true, /_controller\.js$/)
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
```

Here's my `packs/application.js` file:

```js
require('@rails/ujs').start()
require('turbolinks').start()
require('stylesheets/application.scss')
require('stylesheets/custom.scss')
require('src')
import 'controllers'
```

The `application.scss` file contains:

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

None of the custom styles in `custom.scss` apply to the map or its container divs.

Answer (score 1):

*deep breath*

ok  this is really embarrassing

When I originally implemented this site, I took the approach of a `<%= yield :styles %>` in the head and a `<%= yield :scripts %>` at the bottom of the page with `<% content_for(:scripts) do %>` blocks wherever I wanted javascript.

**Narrator's Voice:** He should not have done this.

```
<% content_for(:styles) do %>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<% end %>
```

If I remove my `:styles` block & put the stylesheet tag directly in the head, everything works as expected.